When I make the splash screen the main screen, the app does not open
I want to make a two-screen application. I want to switch from the first location notification screen to the main activity with a button
but the application does not open.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    
    package="com.hadi.ezanvakti">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        
        <activity
        
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
            
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

           </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" />
        
    </application>

</manifest>



(the first screen is not a splash screen, just the name is like that)
SplashActivity.java is here:
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        
        tikla1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.tikla);
        kapat1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.kapat);
        text1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.baslik);
        text2 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text3 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        image1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.konumresmi);
        checkLocationPermission();

        tikla1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View d) {
                    
                    
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        

        kapat1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    }

activity_splash.xml file is here:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/konumi">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/baslik"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Konumunuzu kullanın"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Değişen konumunuza göre otomatik olarak güncellenen namaz vakitleri için Ezan Vakti'nin konumunuzu her zaman kullanmasına izin verin."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Ezan Vakti namaz vakitlerini ve kıble yönünü  göstermek için arka plandaki konumu kullanacak."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/konumresmi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/konumi"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tikla"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:text="Konumu aç"
        android:background="#0009ff"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kapat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:text="Hayir,tesekkurler"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#0009ff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>

I tried to switch to the second screen with a button from the first screen, but the application does not open.
I would be glad if you could help me.

Your issue is in activity_splash.xml. The layout_width and layout_height attributes of your TextView and ImageView are set to match_parent. This means these components overlap your Button and make them unclickable.
Adjust your layout and avoid using match_parent for your TextView and ImageView. You should change its layout_width and layout_height to wrap_content combined with adjusting other attributes to get the expected layout.
For example:
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/baslik"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Konumunuzu kullanın"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Değişen konumunuza göre otomatik olarak güncellenen namaz vakitleri için Ezan Vakti'nin konumunuzu her zaman kullanmasına izin verin."
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ezan Vakti namaz vakitlerini ve kıble yönünü  göstermek için arka plandaki konumu kullanacak."
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/konumresmi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/konumi"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

